# The $T\rightarrow \infty $ limit in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, time-evolution

I am new to quantum field theory. Prior to this, I have been using quantum mechanics for a few years.

I am reading the book by A. Zee, ''quantum field theory in a nutshell'', 2nd Ed..

On page 18,  after equation 4, he takes the limit of $T \rightarrow \infty $.

This looks strange and not motivated. In quantum mechanics, we often have to study the time evolution of a system for a finite time interval, the infinite time limit is irrelevant in many cases.

But here the $T\rightarrow \infty $ limit is considered foremost.

Moreover, even for the $T \rightarrow \infty $ limit, we have an integral of $\int_0^\infty $, not $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }$, so it does not cover the whole spacetime.

So what is the idea here? What is the purpose or the reason?

[image]

Comment: That does appear to be a mistake, the integral should be from $-T$ to $T$ to integrate over "all of spacetime". As a general advice, if you want a correct *technical* account of QFT, don't read Zee, there are even more handwaves in there than usual for presentations of QFT :P

Answer (score 2):

The S-matrix, the basic quantity of interest in quantum field theory applied to elementary particle physics, is defined by the asymptotic behavior of a collision of particles thought to be begun at time $T\to-\infty$ and to end at time $T\to+\infty$. Compared to the consideration of finite times, the formulas enormously simplify, and in view of the very short duration of a collision, the duration of observation is very large, so that $\infty$ is a good approximation to it.